# Image object white background showing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have an Image object that gets resized to the containers size when the image loads.
The images that it will load are dynamic in size so after resize I end up with a sliver of the image object's white background showing.

How can I make the Image object not have a white background and be transparent.
Parts of the PNG's have transparent parts but show up as white due to the white background of the object is it loaded into.

```
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" headerHeight="20" >

  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      public function set source( val:String ):void{
        this.img.source = val;
      }
      private function onLoad( e:Event ):void{
        // resize image on load to fit
        var scale:Number = (this.height - 38) / this.img.contentHeight; // 38 is adjustment for headheight and padding
        this.img.scaleX = scale;
        this.img.scaleY = scale;
      }
    ]]> 
  </mx:Script>

  <!-- how do I make this image object have a transparent background -->
  <mx:Image id="img" complete="onLoad(event)" />

</mx:Panel>
```

[EDIT]
In the screen shot visible are 2 of the objects made from the code I posted above.
As you can see there is a white border.
[image]

and here is one of the PNGs
This png has a transparent 1 inch border at 350@PPI this is 72 PPI So a tad smaller
You can not see the the border here obviously but if you drag it to your desktop and open in photoshop you will see it
[image]

[EDIT]
As SuperSaiyen suggested I added backgroundColor="#000000" to the panel and I got this result. As you can see I got a black border now.
[image]

So i went ahead and added backgroundAlpha="0" along with backgroundColor="#000000" to the panel and got this.
[image]

So now I almost have it but there is still that bluish color around it. Its not quite 100% transparent yet.
I really have no idea why the panel background would change the image tag.
I guess some kind of inheritance from the parent is going on.
Still need to get rid of the blue.

Comment: Erm, don't use a panel to contain your image?  If I remember correctly, Panel's content area has a white background. Post a screenshot of the problem.  Could be that your image wasn't saved as transparent.

Comment: @JAX I verified the images and headers are all PNG. So I edited my question to show more info for you

Comment: Wait... Are you using a panel as an item renderer?!  Again, don't use a panel since it has a white background by default and I think some padding as well.

Comment: No the item renderer is an Hbox. The code posted above is a component inside the Hbox. As you can see from the screen capture above there are 2 of the panels showing with the scroll bar under it. Also as you can see the panel is defaulting to the grayish blue background with the image tag having the white background border where the transparency is on the image.

Comment: Just to note this is flex 3 I do not know what flex 4 or the other libraries default to.

Comment: did you try setting the "backgroundAlpha" property for the HBox and the image object both?? that should help I guess.Set the backgroundAlpha=0

Comment: @Neeraj Just tried setting it on HBox didn't help and apparently the Image object cannot resolve attribute backgroundAlpha.

Comment: Try making the image as gif and see if it works.Im just hitting in the  dark, it might help.

Comment: Can't do gif project workflow is png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the scale, try this:

```
<mx:Image id="img" height="{this.height-38}" maintainAspectRatio="true" />
```

I attempted to recreate your issue, and even with the scale I did not see the white borders.
                   [image]

I have a black border because that is the background of the panel...

```
<mx:Panel id="thePanel" headerHeight="20"
              horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
              height="200" width="150"
              backgroundColor="#000000">

        <!-- how do I make this image object have a transparent background -->
        <mx:Image id="img" height="{thePanel.height-38}" maintainAspectRatio="true" />

    </mx:Panel>
```

Edit:
So the background you're seeing is the background of the box behind the panel, not the image (see opaqueBackground prop on panel). What you want then is to set the background of the panel to be the same color as the borders of the panel. Is panel the right container to use? How about a HBox with roudned corners?

```
<mx:VBox id="thePanel" cornerRadius="4" backgroundColor="0xd1dbe9"
             horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
             height="200" width="150"
             paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5">
        <mx:Label text="Bind to title String" />
        <mx:Image id="img" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </mx:VBox>
```

[image]

Comment: ...yes, you don't have a white border. You have a black border. /facepalm.

Comment: The background color i am looking at is on the image tag not the panel

Comment: SuperSaiyen I edited my question to show you results from what you said and added alpha 0  to it. It's close but not totally there yet.

Comment: I figured the color your seeing is on the image tag, thats why i set the background on the panel, to confirm the image was transparent. Odd that its cascading down like that. Any chance you have some panel CSS that sets the panel borders wide, and the background you're seeing is the panel's background?

Comment: No CSS being used at all yet. It appears to me that the blueish tint is the background color from the container of the panel"which is an HBox". The panels all get added to an Hbox so I tried changing the background color on that just to experiment and sure enough the red cascaded down and everything turned red.

Comment: The background is of the hbox because panel defaults to a transparent background. Perhaps another component? (edited above)

Comment: Well changing Panel to Canvas worked. So definitely an issue with Panel. Wonder if this is a bug or by design from adobe.

Comment: I believe its by design since there is the opaqueBackground property `http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground`. But setting it causes you to lose all the nice rounded corners.

Comment: Well I awarded the bounty to you and up voted. I went with a Canvas.